# Big Query for getting top 50

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

We have only StoreId. I want to write a query for getting top 50 customerIds based on amount of orders they ordered in last 30 days (One StoreId can have multiple orderId)

Data Modal :

```
Table1 : 
     StoreId : String, NOTNULL  
     CustomerId : String, NOTNULL
     Type : String, NOTNULL (Either visit or order, we are looking for order)
     OrderId : String (NOTNULL if Type is order)
     Timestamp : Timestamp

Table2 : 
     
     StoreId : String, NOTNULL  
     OrderId : String, NOTNULL
     AmountOfOrder: Float, NOTNULL
```

NOTE - I am still in learning phase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following query logic, if you do not need `TotalOrders` then remove it from `select`.

```
select customerId, sum(amountOfOrder) as TotalOrders 
     from Table1 t1 join Table2 t2 on t1.StoreId = t2.StoreId and t1.OrderId = t2.OrderId
     Group by customerId
     Order by sum(amountOfOrder) desc
     limit 50;
```